Disable Tkinter button without changing the button color
I'm doing a flip & match game, and it can work as well, but I am trying to make my UI interface look better.
From my code, I will disable the button when the button has been clicked, it will auto change to a more white background color (like having a half transparent color at the front of the button). It will make the image look not look well.
Image in disable button
Image without disable button (what i want)
Source Code:
import tkinter as tk
import random
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import pygame


class FlipnMatchGame:

    # Flip and Match Game init method
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Flip and Match Memory Game")
       
        self.button_size = 100 

        self.images = [self.getImage(f'icon{i}.png') for i in range(1, 19)]
        self.cards = self.createCards()
        self.buttons = []
        self.firstCard = None
        self.secondCard = None
        self.button1 = None
        self.button2 = None
        self.imagePairs = 0
        self.numFlip = 0
        self.createButtons()

    def getImage(self, filepath):
        img = Image.open(filepath)
        img = img.resize((100, 100))  
        return ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)

    def createCards(self):
        card_values = self.images * 2  
        random.shuffle(card_values)
        return card_values

    def createButtons(self):
        for i in range(6):
            row = []
            for j in range(6):
                button = tk.Button(self.root, text='?', width=10, height=5,command=(lambda i=i, j=j: self.flipCard(i, j)),font=("Arial", 10), padx=0, pady=0)
                button.grid(row=i, column=j, padx=1, pady=1)
                row.append(button)
            self.buttons.append(row)

    def flipCard(self, i, j):
        if self.firstCard is None:
            self.firstCard = self.cards[i * 6 + j]
            self.button1 = self.buttons[i][j]
            self.button1.config(image=self.firstCard, height=80, width=80, state=tk.DISABLED) 
            self.button1.config(text='')  
        elif self.secondCard is None:
            self.secondCard = self.cards[i * 6 + j]
            self.button2 = self.buttons[i][j]
            self.button2.config(image=self.secondCard, height=80, width=80, state=tk.DISABLED)  
            self.button2.config(text='')  
            self.root.after(500, self.checkSame)

    def checkSame(self):
        if self.firstCard == self.secondCard:
            self.playSound("correct.mp3") 
            self.numFlip += 1
            self.imagePairs += 1 
            if self.imagePairs == 18:
                self.gameDone()
        else:
            self.numFlip += 1
            self.playSound("wrong.mp3")  
            self.button1.config(image='', text='?', height=5, width=10,state=tk.NORMAL)
            self.button2.config(image='', text='?', height=5, width=10,state=tk.NORMAL)

        self.firstCard = None
        self.secondCard = None
        self.button1 = None
        self.button2 = None

    def playSound(self, sound_file):
        sound = pygame.mixer.Sound(sound_file) 
        sound.play()  

    def gameDone(self):
        for row in self.buttons:
            for button in row:
                button.config(state='disabled')
        winner_label = tk.Label(self.root, text=("Game Over !! \n number of fliping = "+ str(self.numFlip)), font=("Arial", 24))
        winner_label.grid(row=6, column=0, columnspan=6)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pygame.mixer.init() 
    pygame.mixer.music.load("bgm.mp3")
    pygame.mixer.music.play(-1) 
    root = tk.Tk()
    game = FlipnMatchGame(root)
    root.mainloop()

May I know it is possible if I want to disable the button without changing the button color or styling?

Instead of setting the button to be in a disabled state, you can configure the button to have no command execute when it is clicked, thus removing its functionality but keeping the appearance:
<button variable name>.config(<other options>, command=None)

Sample here:
Disabling a button but visually keeping it as if it wasn't disabled

You can set a mouse button binding ('<Button>') on the button widget to prevent it from being clicked without altering its appearance.
This also has the advantage over simply setting command=None in that clicking the button won't cause it to visually "press" down - instead it will just do nothing (and you won't have to re-assign the command later because it will remain unchanged).
button.bind('<Button>', 'break')  # 'break' to stop processing the mouse event

You can later re-enable the button by removing this binding
button.unbind('<Button>')


OP is saying that From my code, I will disable the button when the button has been clicked, it will auto change to a more white background color (like having a half transparent color at the front of the button). It will make the image look not look well

@toyotaSupra Yes, I read the question

Try putting the command for the button as a variable. Once the button is clicked, change the variable to None or to an error message showing that "you have already clicked this button" using an if statement. Good job on using classes, that's a nice way to organize your code.

OP is saying that From my code, I will disable the button when the button has been clicked, it will auto change to a more white background color (like having a half transparent color at the front of the button). It will make the image look not look well

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
